# Recommended practice when having to use "from-to-date" in a mobile application

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, reports, datetimepicker

I'm working on this mobile application that should display a lightweight report. However, I've ended up in an interesting discussion with my colleauges, and thought I'd seek some advice.

Our discussion is this;
When displaying a lightweight report on a mobile device (phone, not tablet), is it cumbersome for the user to first select the dates in a separate view before being sent to the report, or should the report itself contain two datepickers? Furthermore, if selecting the last choice, should the report display a predefined timespan?

Comment: Do you have any screen shots of either design?

Comment: I'm sorry. As of right now this is a discussion where we seek advice for better practices :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer because it depends on what your users expect and this may vary from system to system (depending on its specific nature) and from user to user.

**Is it possible to say what timespan user would be interested most commonly?** Maybe last month or so?

**If the answer is "yes":** You should display report for predefined timespan but allow him/her to modify it. Optionally, you can give him/her some predefined options to choose, like "last week" and "last month".

**If the answer is "no":** You should present the datepickers as the initial step.

**If it depends on the user:** Use any of the above, but let users modify it in settings. Optionally, you can let your users create templates and even present him/her some predefined ones (last week, last month...).

**If you don't know it:** This is tricky - as it mostly depends on the system/user, try to present any of the above but also test it (via A/B tests or a poll) until you know what users prefer. If there is a strong preference (like 80-20) of one over another - implement this option. If the difference between what users choose is slight, it should be based on a per-user setting.

Remember that if you decide to display a report without the additional screen, you can place the datepickers on some overlay to not make users reload a page to access them.

Comment: Thank you for your brief, yet very nice answer :) I'll be sure to bring this up in the discussion!